# Creating a makefile for a C++ Project

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm currently trying to write a Makefile which searches the current directory and all sub-directories for C++ files, then compiles them one by one (**if** they haven't already been compiled or edited since the last time it was compiled) into an individual Object file at the location ./Objects, before finally using the Object files and linking them all into the final program.

I've figured out how to find all the files using the "shell find" command. However, I'm stuck trying to figure out how to compile the source files into objects file one at a time.

Here's my code:

```
Appname := App
#The Directory
ObjectsDir := ./Objects

#Find all the source files
SrcFiles = $(shell find . -name "*.cpp")
#Get their names only
SrcFilesName = $(notdir $(SrcFiles))
#Add a .o suffix for the Object files name
ObjectsSuffix = $(addsuffix .o, $(SrcFilesName))
#Add the prefix "Objects/" as I wish to output all the objects to ./Objects
#A Source Files such as "./Test/Source/Test.cpp" becomes "./Objects/Test.cpp.o"
Objects = $(addprefix ./Objects/, $(ObjectsSuffix))

#Compiler related Variables
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++20 -fsanitize=address  
CPPFLAGS = -DDEBUG -I ./Game/Headers -I ./Engine/Headers -I ./Engine/Headers/External
LDLIBS = $(shell sdl2-config --libs) -l dl

all : $(Appname)

$(Appname) : $(Objects)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(Objects) -o $(Appname) $(LDLIBS)

#The Problematic rule
#I would like this to run once per source file if they haven't been compiled or changed/edited, so that I don't end up recompiling the entire code base
$(ObjectsDir)/%.o: %.cpp
    mkdir -p Objects
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -MMD -MP -c $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)
```

Note: The makefile currently works when all source files are in the base directory. However, when having a more complex layout, with multiple sub-directories errors such as `make: *** No rule to make target 'Objects/Engine.cpp.o', needed by 'App'.  Stop.` occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone in the future wondering how to setup a makefile, here's my final makefile.

```
Appname := App
#Output Dir for Object and dependency files
ObjectsDir := ./Objects

#Find all the source files
SrcFiles := $(shell find . -name "*.cpp")
#Create a variable holding all the objects
Objects := $(patsubst %.cpp,$(ObjectsDir)/%.o,$(SrcFiles))

#Compiler Flags
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++20 -fsanitize=address  
CPPFLAGS = -DDEBUG -I ./Game/Headers -I ./Engine/Headers -I ./Engine/Headers/External
LDLIBS = $(shell sdl2-config --libs) -l dl

.PHONY: all

all : $(Appname)

#Link the object files
$(Appname) : $(Objects)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(Objects) -o $(Appname) $(LDLIBS)

#Rule: For every object file require a dependency file and a C++ file
#1. Create the Folder
#2. Create Dependency File
#3. Create Object File
$(ObjectsDir)/%.o: %.cpp
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(ObjectsDir)

run:
    ./$(Appname)

#Include the dependency files
Deps = $(Objects:%.o=%.d)
-include $(Deps)
```

Comment: The `makefile` can be much simpler if using https://github.com/cppfw/prorab

Answer (score 2):

In a pattern rule, the stem (the part that matches the `%`) will be identical in the target and the prerequisites.  So if your target is `./Objects/foo.o` then the stem is `foo` and the prerequisite is `foo.cpp`.

But, you don't have a `foo.cpp`, so that rule doesn't match.  Make can't find any other rule that matches, so it says it doesn't know how to build that target.

Just because you may have some other file, like `some/subdir/foo.cpp`, doesn't mean anything to make it wasn't looking for that file, it was looking for `foo.cpp`.

In general, taking source files from lots of different directories and putting the build output all into the *same* directory is not how make wants to work (besides, it's usually a bad idea; what happens if you accidentally create two different source files with the same name in two different directories?)

However make does provide a feature that will make this work: `VPATH` will allow make to search for source files in other directories.  If you use this in your makefile:

```
SrcFiles := $(shell find . -name "*.cpp")

SrcFileDirs := $(sort $(dir $(SrcFiles))

VPATH := $(SrcFileDirs)
```

then it should work (you should always use `:=` with `$(shell ...)` for efficiency).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! It solved my problem flawlessly. Just two question, why is it required to sort the directories for the source files? And how do you recommend me to structure my makefile?

Comment: The `sort` function is not absolutely required, but it has a side-effect that not only does it sort things but it removes duplicates.  Since the result of the `dir` will be every directory listed once for each source file in that directory, the sort removes those duplicates which is a bit more efficient.

Comment: Usually I suggest that the object files keep the same directory structure as the source files, just in a separate top-level directory.  So if your sources are `foo/bar.cpp`, `biz/baz.cpp`, etc. then you'd use `Objects := $(patsubst %.cpp,$(ObjectsDir)/%.o,$(SrcFiles))` then you can just use the pattern rule you had originally: `$(ObjectsDir)/%.o : %.cpp` and you don't need VPATH.  In your recipe you need to add `mkdir -p $(@D)` to create the directory before invoking the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule `$(ObjectsDir)/%.o: $(SrcFiles)` says that for *each individual object file*, it depends on *all source files*. That also means that `$^` is all your source files, not just a single source file.

One simple fix that will at least cause things to compile with your specified behavior:

```
$(ObjectsDir)/%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    mkdir -p Objects
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -MMD -MP -c $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)
```

This will mean that if you update a .cpp file, the appropriate .cpp.o file will be recompiled, and other cpp files won't be. However, if you update a header file it depends on, this dependency won't be processed, and you'll get false negatives where something needs to be recompiled but isn't. You're generating dependency-tracking files with the -MMD -MP flags, and you can use them by adding the following to your Makefile:

```
Deps = $(Objects:%.o=%.d)
-include $(Deps)
```

That will more robustly track the actual dependencies your translation units have, instead of just the "Foo.cpp.o depends on Foo.cpp" one.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt and concise reply. One problem I have when using ```$(ObjectsDir)/%.cpp.o: %.cpp``` is that I get the following error ```make: *** No rule to make target 'Objects/Engine.cpp.o', needed by 'App'.  Stop.``` Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately the toy example I've constructed doens't demonstrate this issue. I'm not sure exactly what's causing the difference between them.

Comment: May I have a look at your toy example?

Comment: [Makefile](https://pastebin.com/b49Rg5LM). Added some pretty trivial `Foo.cpp` `Foo.hpp` `Bar.cpp` files in the local directory whose contents shouldn't matter all that much.

Comment: Have you tried moving the source files around into sub-dirs? The makefile worked when all source files are in the base dir and not when they are in sub-dirs